# Changing the tab design in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, qt4, qtabwidget

How to edit the tabs separately, I want to place the background image on tab 1 different from tab 2.

```
QWidget::tab {
border-image: url(:/Tabs/tab_notclick.png);
min-width:96px;
min-height:18px;
}
QWidget::tab2 {
borrder-image: url(:/Tabs/tab2_notclick.png);
min-width:96px;
min-height:18px;
}
QWidget::tab:selected{
border-image: url(:/Tabs/tab_click.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not fix it but in the tab2 part of the stylesheet border is spelt borrder, which would end up making that part of the stylesheet not work as expected.

This:

```
borrder-image: url(:/Tabs/tab2_notclick.png);
```

Needs to be this:

```
border-image: url(:/Tabs/tab2_notclick.png);
```

Please let me know if this fixes the problem or not.